# Reading from input file

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble reading from an input file.
The input file looks like this

Lionel Messi -10 43

Fernando Torres 9 -29

Cristiano Ronaldo 7 31

Wayne Rooney 10 37

Neymar 17 29

Andres Iniesta 8 32

Robin van Persie 19 20

Lionel Messi 10 43

Xavi Hernandez 6 36

Mesut Özil 10 38

Didier Drogba 10 35

Fernando Torres 9 29

Kaká 10 17

The problem is that I cant use the getline function because I want to store the name into a single variable to store into an array, and the first number into a variable and the second into another variable. I also tried to use the peek function but I have never learned that so I had no success with it.
If anyone knows how to read until the end of the name and store it into a single variable that would be much appreciated.

This is what my code looks like when im reading from the input file

```
while(!fin.eof())
    {

     fin >> first >> last >> num >> point;

     if (num > 0 && point > 0)
     {
             list[i].firstname = first;
             list[i].lastname = last;
             list[i].number = num;
             list[i].points = point;
             i++;
     }
     else if (num < 0 || point < 0)
     {
             reject[j].firstname = first;
             reject[j].lastname = last;
             reject[j].number = num;
             reject[j].points = point;
             j++;
     }

    }
```

This works perfectly if the input has a first and a last name. I know the problem is
on the
    fin >> first >> last >> num >> point;

but i am not exactly sure how to put first and last (and possibly middle) together

Comment: Ah, but you can use `getline`.

Comment: Is the "space" between the parts of names the same kind as between the last of the name and the numbers? It would help a lot if it's a tab character `'\t'` between the last of the names and the numbers. Otherwise, you'll (probably) want to read a whole line, and then remove the number bits from the back of the string (using `std::string::find_last_of` and `std::string::substr` for example)

Comment: Yes all of the spaces are the same between the names and numbers. So its possible to store the whole line into a string variable, and then remove the two numbers from the end of the string and put them into separate variables?

Comment: This is a pretty good first question :)

Comment: And the usual comment: `while ( !fin.eof() )` is always an error.

Comment: Right... `while(!fin.eof())
    {

     fin >> first >> last >> num >> point;`  should be just `while(fin >> first >> last >> num >> point) {`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::getline` to extract the lines, the parse the line into a `std::vector` of space separated words. Then you know that `words.size() - 2` of the words are part of the name. For example:

```
std::fstream in("in.txt");
std::string line;

// Extract each line from the file
while (std::getline(in, line)) {
  std::istringstream line_stream(line);

  // Now parse line_stream into a vector of words
  std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(line_stream),
                                 (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()));

  int name_word_count = words.size() - 2;
  if (name_word_count > 0) {
    // Concatenate the first name_word_count words into a name string
    // and parse the last two words as integers
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not a bad solution.  I hadn't considered the fact that `>>` into a string uses white space as a separator.  (Of course, as you've written it, it won't compile.  But you're not the first to fall prey to the most embarrassing parse.  Wrap one (or both) of the arguments to the constructor of `words` with an extra set of parentheses.

Comment: @JamesKanze Hm, I'm wondering why that was happening. Surely the first argument can't possible be a type (it has `line_stream` in it)?

Comment: `line_stream` will be interpreted as the name of the first parameter.

Comment: And just a personal preference, but I prefer wrapping the args in extra parentheses to introducing an extra variable.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh hell, that's evil.

Comment: Is parsing a vector the same as parsing for an array? I have never heard about parsing before right now, sorry about that.

Comment: @kylekolossus The vector is not being parsed. The line of text is. To parse a line of text generally means to split it up into separate tokens or, in this case, words.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you need to use `getline`, and then parse
the line.  One solution for parsing it might be to split the
line just before the first digit, then trim the first half, and
use it for the name, and parse the second half using an 
`std::istringstream` to read the two numbers.  This will fail,
of course, if someone has a digit as part of their name, but
that seems to me to be a legitimate limitation.  In other words,
for each line, you'd do:

```
std::string::iterator first_digit
        = std::find_if( line.begin(), line.end(), IsDigit() );
if ( first_digit == line.end() ) {
    //  format error...
} else {
    name = trim( std::string( line.begin(), first_digit ) );
    std::istringstream parser( std::string( first_digit, line.end() ) );
    parser >> firstNumber >> secondNumber >> std::ws;
    if ( !parser || parser.get() != EOF ) {
        //  format error...
    } else {
        //  Do what ya gotta do.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
std::string str;
while(getline(infile, str))
{
  std::string::size_type pos;
  pos = str.find_last_of(' ');
  if (pos == std::string::npos || pos < 1)
  {
      cout << "Something not right with this string: " << str << endl;
      exit(1);
  }
  int last_number = stoi(str.substr(pos));
  str = str.substr(0, pos-1);    // Remove the number and the space.
  pos = str.find_last_of(' ');
  if (pos == std::string::npos || pos < 1)
  {
      cout << "Something not right with this string: " << str << endl;
      exit(1);
  }
  int first_number = stoi(str.substr(pos));
  str = str.substr(0, pos-1); 
  // str now contains the "name" as one string. 

  // ... here you use last_number and first_number and str to do what you need to do. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use getline(); Use the two parameter method, passing it a stream and '\n' as the delimiter.

Assign the entire line into one string, then split the string using a space as a delimiter, and covert the second two into integers.

Comment: Space fails on spaces in name (which is variable per name)

Comment: Updated answer to address that.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It's still possible this way... just use the last two elements as integers and all the other elements (no matter how many) as name. Given there is a fixed amount of integers after each name.

Comment: @Layne, I'm fine what that - but the answer needs to reflect it :)

Answer (score 0):

1.) Open the file

```
std::ifstream myFile("somewhere.txt");
```

2.) Check to see if the file is open

```
if(myFile.is_open())
```

3.) Read until end of file

```
while(!myFile.eof())
```

4.) Read the first name into a first name array

```
myFile >> firstName[numberOfPeople];
```

5.) Read the last name into the last name array

```
myFile >> lastName[numberOfPeople];
```

6.) Read the integer into an integer array

```
myFile >> integer[numberOfPeople];
```

7.) Increment number of people

```
numberOfPeople++;
```

8.) When while is done, close file

```
myFile.close();
```

9.) If file did not open, report the error.

```
else
   std::cout << "\nFile did not open. " << std::endl;
```

You can use the getline function, you just have to parse the string.  This can be achieved using strtok.

Comment: You don't ever want to use `strtok`.

Comment: And you don't really need the close.  (You do for output, because you have to check that it succeeds, but for input, you don't.)

Comment: And re "bad code in this thread": `while ( !myFile.eof() )` is definitely an error, and very bad code.

Comment: @JamesKanze How is `while (!myFile.eof())` an error?  It works just fine.  The bad code I was referring to was using vectors/iterators for something as simple as file I/O.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  Read the definition of `std::ios_base::eof()`.  Basically, you complain about bad code, but post a solution which doesn't work, where as all of the others do.  Splitting the line into a vector is actually a very good solution.  Any solution which involves parsing the line, other than using an `std::istringstream`, will involve iterators.  And you've got to distinguish between ``'\n'` and other white space, because the records in the file are separated by `'\n'`.

Comment: I just compiled the code on Visual Studio and it indeed works...  I have no idea what you are talking about.  Using a vector is ALOT of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't begin to work.  You just haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution to your problem (mostly for my own learning). It works as intended, but it feels a bit lengthy.

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

struct PlayerData {
  std::string name;
  int number;
  int points;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PlayerData& p) {
  os<<"Name: "<<p.name<<", Number: "<<p.number<<", Points: "<<p.points;
  return os;
}

PlayerData parse(const std::string& line) {
  PlayerData data;  
  std::stringstream ss(line);  
  std::vector<std::string> tokens;
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss),
            std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
            std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(tokens));
  data.points = std::stoi(tokens.at(tokens.size() - 1));
  data.number = std::stoi(tokens.at(tokens.size() - 2));
  for(auto it=tokens.begin(); it!=tokens.end()-2; ++it) {
    data.name.append(" ");
    data.name.append(*it);
  }
  return data;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string line;
  std::vector<PlayerData> players;  

  { // scope for fp                                    
    std::ifstream fp(argv[1], std::ios::in);
    while(!fp.eof()) {
      std::getline(fp, line);
      if(line.size()>0) {
        players.push_back(parse(line));
      }
    }
  } // end of scope for fp

  // print list of players, or do whatever you want with it.
  for(auto p:players) {
    std::cout<<p<<std::endl;    
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile with a version of g++ supporting C++11 (in my case gcc 4.7.2).

```
[Prompt] g++ -oparseline parseline.cpp -std=c++11 -O2
[Prompt] ./parseline players.txt
Name:  Fernando Torres, Number: 9, Points: -29
Name:  Cristiano Ronaldo, Number: 7, Points: 31
Name:  Wayne Rooney, Number: 10, Points: 37
Name:  Neymar, Number: 17, Points: 29
Name:  Andres Iniesta, Number: 8, Points: 32
Name:  Robin van Persie, Number: 19, Points: 20
Name:  Lionel Messi, Number: 10, Points: 43
Name:  Xavi Hernandez, Number: 6, Points: 36
Name:  Mesut Özil, Number: 10, Points: 38
Name:  Didier Drogba, Number: 10, Points: 35
Name:  Fernando Torres, Number: 9, Points: 29
Name:  Kaká, Number: 10, Points: 17
```